why weak L2 fourier tranform locally L1 integrable
If $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$ and let $F(f)$ be weak $L^2$ weak fourier transform. How to show $F(f)$ is locally $L^1$ integrable function. Can someone give me some idea. I am confused. Thank you.

Any $L^{2}$ function is locally $L^{1}$.

Thank you so much..I missed this..Locally integrable means checking integrability on compact set.
